# How to find GP Name from GP English Name in ADMX file

Tags: google-chrome, group-policy, intune

hi i am currently moving gpo's to intune. i have read all of microsoft's documentation but one thing they do not cover is how to derive the gp name (in admx file) from the gp english name (what you would see in gp edit console). For non custom ADMX they say you can use the csp console like the image below:

[image: csp]

but i am wanting to move over gpos that use custom admx, such as google chrome. I can go into the gp edit console and see the "Action on startup" gpo for example in the following location: Google/Google Chrome - Default Settings (users can override)/Startup, Home page and New Tab page

but how do i associate that with a policy entry in the chrome.admx file? just by going through the file i see this entry that most closely resembles what I want to do but how can i be sure it is the right one?

```
<policy class="Both" displayName="$(string.RestoreOnStartup)" explainText="$(string.RestoreOnStartup_Explain)" key="Software\Policies\Google\Chrome" name="RestoreOnStartup" presentation="$(presentation.RestoreOnStartup)">
      <parentCategory ref="Startup"/>
      <supportedOn ref="SUPPORTED_WIN7"/>
      <elements>
        <enum id="RestoreOnStartup" valueName="RestoreOnStartup">
          <item displayName="$(string.RestoreOnStartup_RestoreOnStartupIsNewTabPage)">
            <value>
              <decimal value="5"/>
            </value>
          </item>
          <item displayName="$(string.RestoreOnStartup_RestoreOnStartupIsLastSession)">
            <value>
              <decimal value="1"/>
            </value>
          </item>
          <item displayName="$(string.RestoreOnStartup_RestoreOnStartupIsURLs)">
            <value>
              <decimal value="4"/>
            </value>
          </item>
        </enum>
      </elements>
    </policy>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you download the chrome policy templates zip, go to windows\admx\en-us folder. There’s a chrome.adml that will contain all the string substitutions for the admx. Admx + locale adml = what you see in the Gp editor window.